# eclipse hot code relace failed window disappeared

Tags: java, eclipse

The window named 'Hot Code Replace Failed' is very helpful for me, but I choose the 'don't show any more' not intentionally, how can I make it show again?

Comment: Did you checked Project->Build Automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I have these options:

- Intercept hot code replacement failures;
- On hot replacement failure.

on my server overview page, double click on my server in the "Servers" view.

Checking the first and setting the second to "Show Dialog" restored back the window.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can look at "window"-->"show view"

Comment: I find the preference->java->debug->hot code replace, I choose all of them, but still can not see the window when hot code replace failed